# In order to support Failover in mongodb we have to configure replica set along with Autosharding?

Tags: mongodb

I am undergoing testing on mongodb AutoSharding and failover.Whether replicaset has to configured along with mongodb autosharding inorder to support the failover?Please help out...If u know how to configure replica set for supporting failover please explain me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharding and Replication are two separate topics. Replica Sets support failover. Sharding supports spreading data and requests across multiple servers.

There is a great tutorial that shows you how to set up replica sets here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Tutorial